# Compatible Ram for my i3 Core Laptop, Intel® HM55 Express Chipset

Tags: ram

Please suggest me best Ram(8GB) that is compatible with my laptop. Following is my laptop configuration.

http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/content/cnt-specs/VPCEB1M0E/list

Answer (score 0):

DDR3 SDRAM 1066 MHz is enough info to buy memory stick, just see available vendors, I would buy Kingston, but do not know, whether it is available at your location. By the way, usually there are 2 slots for memory, if 8GB is max, it is better to buy 2 sticks 4GB each, so they will work in dual mode.

However your question is out of SO topics.